# Workaround for iOS 10-12 WebKit (Safari/Chrome) iframe focus bug

Tags: ios, iframe, webkit, focus, mobile-safari

I've searched for this specific issue here on StackOverflow and the various Apple/WebKit bug reporting systems but have yet to find it specifically cited (which just doesn't seem possible).

The problem:
On our payment page we have various form fields (inputs & selects). For PCI/security purposes we have an iframe that serves the credit card number field (the iframe *only* has that one field - nothing else).

**<s>The issue is that for *just* iOS users, they sometimes cannot put the focus on the credit card number field.</s> There appears to be 2 different, but related iOS webkit bugs. See the UPDATE below.**

If they simply navigate down from one field to another, it usually works. But if they bounce around fields, they can get into the scenario where try-as-they-might <s>they cannot get the focus into the credit card number field</s> it doesn't look like the credit card field gets the focus (appears to be a rendering issue).

Initially we thought maybe there was JS or some invisible DIV getting into the way, but I eventually was able to create an [HTML-only example to recreate the problem](https://codepen.io/stuartclan/project/full/ZzqzkJ/). (Instructions on how to recreate the issue are on the example page.) Linking to codepen requires I include some code:

```
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
```

I've consistently been able to recreate this issue on iOS 10-12 devices (an iOS 9 device didn't seem to have the problem).

For posterity I'm going to supply the work-around I came across in a separate, but semi-related WebKit bug. However, I was wondering if others out there had stumbled upon this problem and discovered other work-arounds.

## UPDATE:

After digging in further I've discovered we're suffering from 2 separate bugs. The first is mostly as I describe above, but seems to be more of a rendering issue where iOS doesn't *look* like it's putting the focus on a field. However, if you go to the <s>codepen example</s> [new example](https://ios-iframe.azurewebsites.net/) I setup and follow the steps, even when it doesn't look like the field has the focus, if you type the text will render correctly.

The second problem is less likely to happen but is more detrimental. It requires 3 criteria to trip:

1. The iframe's source has to be cross-origin
2. Parent page is attaching an event listener to either touchstart, touchmove or touchend (even as simple as an empty function call)
3. The iframe’s field is off-screen when a different field has focus and the keyboard is present.

The result of these 3 things is that the user cannot place focus on the iframe field at all (typing goes nowhere although document.activeElement shows the last parent page input having focus). Reestablishing the ability to get the focus in the iframe can be difficult, generally need to have a parent page input that can be focused while the iframe field is *visible* then the user can move their focus to the iframe field from there.

If any of the 3 criteria is changed (not cross-domain, no event listeners on those 3 touch events or the iframe is visible), then only the first – less-prohibitive – bug is present.

I will update my "answer" below with this realization as well.

**Update 2:** The [new example I put up shows both bugs](https://ios-iframe.azurewebsites.net/) in action; the first page is Bug #1 with a link to the cross-origin Bug #2 example.

Comment: Problem is resolved in my environment by adding @Ryan L's suggestion `document.addEventListener('touchstart', {});` in the IFrame.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem is resolved in my environment by adding @Ryan L's suggestion `document.addEventListener('touchstart', {});` in the IFrame.

This is good as it's very simple to add and is specific to the IFrame,  not affecting the container page.

Problem description:  cannot 'touch' (select, edit) another form field on Safari running on iDevices (phone & pad) running iOS 12.  This only happens on pages in an IFrame where the container page has added some touch events.  Very obscure set of conditions that are difficult to debug.

Answer (score 5):

I believe I have found a fix for this frustrating little bug, and like most bugs it's a super simple fix.

All that needs to be done is to apply a the following css to the input within the iframe.

```
    input:hover {
        cursor: text
    }
```

Here's an updated example: https://codepen.io/ryanoutloud/project/full/AEKGjj

Now as to the bug itself, the focus is actually on the intended field and any entry from the keyboard will be registered properly. Once typing begins the caret jumps into proper position. The
issue I found with the `ontouchstart=""` solution is that it simply removes the caret from view entirely once focus is placed on a field.

***Update per my comment below***
The above in conjunction with the following should resolve this issue.
By adding the following within the iframe as well.

document.addEventListener('touchstart', {});

Comment: Hey Ryan,

Thanks for digging further into this. It does seem like your workaround is better than the `ontouchstart` approach. However, that fix only seems to alleviate the first of the two bugs I updated my post with (the rendering issue).

Any thoughts on the second (more impactful, but also less typical) bug?

I couldn't use codepen to create a cross-origin iframe test, so I stood up a simple [example on Azure](https://ios-iframe.azurewebsites.net/).  The landing page shows Bug #1 (with a button to toggle your CSS fix) with a link at the top to Bug #2. Updated original post with link.

Comment: FYI, the workaround for bug #1 that we're testing is a little more focused (in order to exclude radio & checkboxes getting the text cursor): `input[type=text]:hover, input[type=number]:hover, input[type=email]:hover, input[type=tel]:hover, input[type=password]:hover, textarea:hover {
 cursor: text
}`

Comment: J, make sure the workaround for bug #1 is only within the iframe, not the parent. Also, try adding the following within the iframe as well. This combo seems to fix both 1 and 2 from my side.

`document.addEventListener('touchstart', {});`

Comment: @Ryan, I finally had the chance to add the iframe fix you suggested to a [new example page](https://ios-iframe.azurewebsites.net/index-cross-fix). It does appear that the `document.addEventListener` added to the _iframe_ source seems to fix Bug #1 and #2 - at least within the iframe. Bug #1 still seems to be a problem when coming out of the iframe to an input on the parent page (see example), but that's _fairly negligible_ compared to the original two bugs. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan:  Please update this answer with the `document.addEventListener('touchstart', {});`  text;  this fixed this exceedingly irritating problem in my IFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the work-around I stumbled upon: **add `ontouchstart=""` to each of the form input elements** (probably selects too).

This came from one of the work-arounds provided on [this WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=185001) related to outer page click events not dispatching properly to an iframe (in the context of zooming).

I have not pushed this to production yet, but initial tests seem to indicate this works. I did have to put this on both the parent & iframe form elements to fully fix the problem. I'll probably leverage JavaScript to attach this to the form fields without needing to add the property to each form element.

Open to any other suggestions or concerns with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  window.focus()
  $(':focus').focus()
});
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: A code-only answer is a low-quality answer. Add some explanation to why this code-snippet works.